# Upgraded to Debian Jessie from Wheezy, can't mount NTFS disks anymore

Tags: debian, ntfs, debian-jessie, ntfs-3g

After upgrading from Debian Wheezy to Debian Jessie, I can't mount my NTFS partitions anymore.

One error message which I get is:

> Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
>   The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
>   could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `ntfs-3g` from Jessie has a bug. 
Installing the package from the unstable Sid version solves the problem for me.

Dowload package from :

https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/ntfs-3g/download

and install as root with :

```
sudo dpkg -i ntfs-3g_2015.3.14AR.1-1_amd64.deb
```